# Google Vision API Text Detection with Node.js set Language hint

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, vision-api

I'm using `@google-cloud/vision` with Node.js

I use the sample code as below

```js
async function quickstart() {
  try {
    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
    const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

    // Creates a client
    const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

    // Performs label detection on the image file
    const [result] = await client.textDetection('./test.jpg');
    const texts = result.textAnnotations;
    console.log('Text:');
    texts.forEach((text: string) => console.log(text));
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This is currently working working and return english texts and numbers. I have texts in image which Vision API's Experimental languages. How can I set the language hint as document specified in node.js API?

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr

Answer (score 1):

You can use the batchAnnotateImages method. Eg: something like:

```
const request = {
    features: [{type: 'TEXT_DETECTION'}],
    imageContext: {
        languageHints: ["en-t-i0-handwrit"]
    },
    <other parts of your request>
};
const [response] = await imageAnnotatorClient.batchAnnotateImages({
    requests: [request],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this one to detect my id card in khmer language.
**imageUri** you can use any adress in this case i put url address from google for example.
**languageHints** this is what you want, change it to your languageHints code Here's [a link](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages)!

```
async function quickstart() {
  const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');

  const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

  const request = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "image": {
          "source": {
            "imageUri": "https://pbs.twimg.com/media/Cm_Jj7hUEAALwRF.jpg"
          }
        },
        "features": [
          {
            "type": "DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION"
          }
        ],
        "imageContext": {
          "languageHints": ["km"]
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  const [result] = await client.batchAnnotateImages(request);
  const detections = result.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation;
  console.log(detections.text);
}

quickstart().catch(console.error);
```

the text it's not render correctly when you console the text , just copy it to word or notepad.