# Google Vision text detection for Node.js using base64 encoding

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Just started exploring Google Cloud Vision APIs. From their guide:

```
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();
const fileName = 'Local image file, e.g. /path/to/image.png';
const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileName);
```

However, I wanna use base64 representation of binary image data, since they claim that it's possible to use.

I found this reference on SO:
[Google Vision API Text Detection with Node.js set Language hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138047/google-vision-api-text-detection-with-node-js-set-language-hint)

Instead of `imageUri` I used `"content": string`as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/AnnotateImageRequest). But the SO sample uses `const [result] = await client.batchAnnotateImages(request);`method. I tried using same technique on `const [result] = await client.textDetection(` method and it gave me an error.

So my question is: Is it possible to use base64 encoded string to represent image in order to perform TEXT_DETECTION ? And if so, how?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`content` field need to be `Buffer`.

You use the nodejs client library. The library use the grpc API internally, and grpc API expect `bytes` type at `content` field.

However, JSON API expect `base64 string`.

### References

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#image
https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection

Comment: I think I tried to use byte array first...and for some reason it didn't work, so I went base64 route...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-nodejs) guide and from there edit the lines after the creation of the [client](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-vision/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js#L23) for the following:

```
// Value of the image in base64
const img_base64 = '/9j/...';

const request = {
  image: {
    content: Buffer.from(img_base64, 'base64')
  }
};

const [result] = await client.textDetection(request);
console.log(result.textAnnotations);
console.log(result.fullTextAnnotation);
```

You can take a look at the function [here](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection), read the description of the request parameter, in particular the following part:

> A dictionary-like object representing the image. This should have a
> single key (`source`, `content`).
>
> If the key is `content`, the value should be a Buffer.

Which leads to the structure used in the sample code from before. Opposed to when using `imageUri` or `filename`, which have to be inside of another object which key is `source`, as shown in the [sample](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/vision/latest/v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.html#textDetection-examples).